# Visual C# Clickonce Application with LocalDB (MSSQLLocal) installation on client fail

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, localdb

I recently developed a Visual C# Clickonce application with an attached `.MDF` database file with the connection string of:

```
String connString = String.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True", @"|DataDirectory|\DataBase.mdf");
```

The application reads the data in the database and stores it as a key-value pair in a `Dictionary<obj, obj>`. The database file is built as Content and Copy Always.

Debugging/Running the app on my visual studio 2017 works fine, same as installing the application in my local machine but when I install the application on another computer (even after installing the SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB) the application cannot load/connect with the database. I have read a lot of topics regarding deploying C# with localdb but none of those works.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10, client machine runs on Windows 10

Comment: Don't reference the mdf file in the connection string in causes issues.  I've been told recently that it is required but I believe that was with very old versions of VS.  The newer versions of SQL the database owns the mdf file and the permissions do not allow a connection directly to the mdf file for security purposes. Also do not use AttachDBFilename for sane issue.  Instead use : Initial Catalog=myDataBase.  On remote PC replace (LocalDB) with the name of the PC where database resides.

Comment: @jdweng for localdb to work you will have to provide it the mdf file and i believe there is no other way then doing it in the connection string. I never had problems with it

Comment: are you trying to connect to a localdb that is on another computer ? Not sure if that is possible

Comment: installing the localdb is not enough, you also need to install the native sql server driver which can be found on microsoft downloads

Comment: The .mdf is included in the application as Content upon deployment. The app contains the database which is then installed on a client's computer

Comment: Guido : What version of SQL Server and VS are you using?  Are you using Windows credentials or SQL Server Credentials?

Comment: I have Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (13.0.1601.5) and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition